# string startWith in Matlab

Tags: string, matlab-deployment

I would like to get only the begining of string , is there an equivalent matlab that allows to say : startsWith('It-is') like in java?

Thanks

Answer (score 8):

You can use the [`strfind`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/strfind.html) function to tell if one string starts with another.  The function returns the starting index of each occurrence of the string you're looking for, or an empty array if the string is not found.

```
S = 'Find the starting indices of the pattern string';
strfind(S, 'It-is')
```

If the string started with `'It-is'` then the first index of the array returned by `strfind` would be 1 (i.e. the index of the first character).

Answer (score 3):

For long strings, it is faster to do this

```
s = (numel(a)>=numel(b)) && all(a(1:min(numel(a),numel(b)))==b(1:min(numel(a),numel(b))));
```

in order to have the equivalent to `a.startsWith(b)`.

Answer (score 3):

The option that works best for me is:

```
~isempty(regexp(s, '^It-is', 'once'))
```

The ~isempty allows you to use the expression with logical ORs or ANDs like this:

```
if ~isempty(regexp(s, '^It-is', 'once')) || ~isempty(regexp(s, '^It-was', 'once'))
```

The 'once' parameter is an optimization to ensure you don't keep scanning the string once you have found the match at the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

The trouble with strfind is that it returns a non-scalar result, which limits where you can use it. More straightfoward would be to use [regexp](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexp.html) like so,

```
s = 'It-is true.';
if regexp(s, '^It-is')
  disp('s starts with "It-is"')
end
```

Comment: I do not agree with the comment--you can always wrap `strfind` in an `isempty` to get a boolean.  Also good to keep in mind that the MATLAB implementation of `regexp` is much much slower than `strfind`.

Comment: @mbroshi, no you can't. `isempty(strfind(s, regexp)` is always true, because strfind returns `{[]}` if it haven't found a match.

Comment: Downvoted because `if regexp(s, '^It-is')` gives a error:
> "Conversion to logical from cell is not possible"

Comment: I'm not sure why you say it gives an error. I just confirmed this in the latest MATLAB and and it output as expected.

`>> s = 'It-is true.';
if regexp(s, '^It-is')
  disp('s starts with "It-is"')
end`

`outputs:
s starts with "It-is"
`
In the example **s** is not a cell. Can you provide the context in which you encountered the error?

Answer (score 0):

I want to add that if s is a cell then regexp and strfind return a [cell array](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/cell-arrays.html).
You can use one of two variants in this case:

```
pos = strfind(s, 'It-iss');
if (~isempty(pos{1,1}))
    disp('s starts with "It-is"')
end
```

or

```
pos = regexp(s, '^It-is');
if (~isempty(pos{1,1}))
    disp('s starts with "It-is"')
end
```

You can't directly cast the return value of `regexp` or `strfind` to bool, because they return If there are no matches, `regexp` and `strfind` return a [cell array](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/cell-arrays.html) with empty cell `{[]}`. To access the first cell you need to us ecurled braces operator `pos{1,1}`.

Answer (score 0):

Starting in Matlab2016b, there is a [startsWith](https://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/startswith.html) function:

```
startsWith(your_string, 'It-is')
```

In previous versions, you can use [Bill the Lizard's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10397558/7456923) to make your own function:

```
matches = strfind(your_string, 'It-is');
string_starts_with_pattern = ~isempty(matches) && matches(1) == 1;
```